# Regx for finding links with same begining and different ending

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to find following kind of links having the same beginning but a different ending.

```
http://www.domain.com/buy/best%20iphone%20leather%20case.html
```

the links always start with `http://www.domain.com/buy/` but can end with different links:

```
best%20iphone%20leather%20case.html
best%20ipad%20chargers.html
etc..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your start string is fixed so will just have to use:

```
^http://www\.domain\.com/buy/.*\.html
```

^ is used in regular expression to point beginning with 'string/word/character'.

You may have to escape '/' and '.' putting '\' just before these characters.

Comment: thanks that solved it, i removed the ^ in the start of the expression because it wasnt the begining of the text, but the begining only of the link.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
^http://www\.domain\.com/buy/.+?html
```

Comment: i tried it but it didnt work, only replaced the domain to the correct one.